# Spinner setOnItemSelectedListener not working with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have made a custom spinner to populate a list of image and text that comes from mysql DB
when I tried to select an item from the spinner it doesn't work, even when I debug and put a break point inside the listener it doesn't go in.
My Adapter:

```
 public class SpinnerShopAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<supermarketspinnerGS> {
    private Context mcontext;
    ArrayList<supermarketspinnerGS> SavedListContent;
    public SpinnerShopAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<supermarketspinnerGS> SavedListContent) {
        super(context, 0, SavedListContent);
        this.mcontext = context;
        this.SavedListContent = SavedListContent;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return initView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.spinner_supermarket_row, parent, false
            );
        }

        ImageView imvSupermaket = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_supermarket_imageView);
        TextView tvSupamrketname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_supermarket_name);
        TextView tvIdShop = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_supermarket_idshop);

        supermarketspinnerGS currentItem = getItem(position);

        if (currentItem != null) {
            Glide.with(context).load(currentItem.getImage()).into(imvSupermaket);
            tvSupamrketname.setText(currentItem.getName());
            tvIdShop.setText(currentItem.getIdshop());
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

onCreate code:

```
 spinnerStore = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.saveditemlist_spinner_storeshead);
    adapterHead = new SpinnerShopAdapter(ActivitySavedListItem.this, getListHeadArray);
 spinnerStore.setAdapter(adapterHead);
    spinnerStore.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    supermarketspinnerGS clickedItem = (supermarketspinnerGS) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String clickedshopName = clickedItem.getIdshop();
                  selectedItemText=getListHeadArray.get(spinnerStore.getSelectedItemPosition()).getIdshop();
                    Toast.makeText(ActivitySavedListItem.this, clickedshopName + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

I really don't know what is wrong and looking forward for your help. If you need more details please feel free to ask me I'll be glad to update my post

EDIT : 
XML SPINNER

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_market_shape"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView13"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/saveditemlist_spinner_storeshead"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

spinner_supermarket_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/spinner_supermarket_imageView"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinner_supermarket_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinner_supermarket_idshop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: paste your xml as well

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure but
I think you must set your spinner item click listener in your spinner custom adapter in initView function

like this:

```
 private View initView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.spinner_supermarket_row, parent, false
        );
    }

    ImageView imvSupermaket = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_supermarket_imageView);
    TextView tvSupamrketname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_supermarket_name);
    TextView tvIdShop = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_supermarket_idshop);

    supermarketspinnerGS currentItem = getItem(position);

    if (currentItem != null) {
        Glide.with(context).load(currentItem.getImage()).into(imvSupermaket);
        tvSupamrketname.setText(currentItem.getName());
        tvIdShop.setText(currentItem.getIdshop());
    }

    parent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if(position==CUSTOM_POSITION){ /*do something*/}                

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

I hope it works

Comment: unfortunately it didn't

Answer (score 0):

try to to add clickable=false to all your elements on your xml spinner row

Comment: did you add clickable=false to all your elements expect your RelativeLayout ?

Comment: Yes I have done that, it's not able to catch the event